# How to filter data into new column? sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hallo Dear Stackoverflow users.

Working with sql on sql server

I have searched the forum and the internet, but haven't found information concerning what i want to achieve. Mainly because I don't know the correct terminology.

I have created a new view, and **I would like to filter out different data from a  column (ver_klass) to a newly created column.**

In the below picture is how my view looks like at the moment.

[image]

This is how I would like to represent the view:

```
ver_rayon  |ver_metier |ver_secteur
96         |           |
96         |           |
           | M10       |
           | M11       |
           |           |S1
12         |           |
```

I want to know if it is possible to do that, and how. Thanks a lot

Comment: Which database are you using and what have you tried?

Comment: I am using a custom database in my work alias_dat and I had to load the data from oracle through an ssis package into sql server. Now the data in the ver_klass column is mixed up. I need it for creating roles for reports. I tried adding a new column with a filter but i don't think the syntax worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be managed with a few `CASE` statements. The idea is to check if the first character of `ver_klass` is `M` or `S` and take a different action on each. So in the first case, if it is neither M,S then the value goes to `ver_rayon`. The second and third cases look for `M` and `S` respectively and store to those columns. Since the row matches only one of the three cases, the other two are NULLed.

```
SELECT
 ...
 ...
 CASE WHEN LEFT(ver_klass, 1) <> 'S' AND LEFT(ver_klass, 1) <> 'M' THEN ver_klass ELSE NULL END AS ver_rayon,
 CASE WHEN LEFT(ver_klass, 1) = 'M' THEN ver_klass ELSE NULL END AS ver_metier,
 CASE WHEN LEFT(ver_klass, 1) = 'S' THEN ver_klass ELSE NULL END AS ver_secteur,
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, i will check it out right away. I will then give you feedback on the outcome ; )

Comment: brilliant works like a charm. Happy I learnt something new today ; )